# How to get contact which is lastmodified in Objective - C using CNContact?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cncontact, cncontactstore

I have fetch all contact using `CNContact` from device and modified but I don't get it which one is last modified...so what should I do to get info of last modified contact with it's date.

Comment: Vivek first did you get all contacts from iPhone?

Comment: Where did you save the modified contact?

Comment: yes i got all the contacts from iPhone with all the details @user3182143

Comment: i'm saving in existing contact which one is modified with it's unique identifier.. @user3182143

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addressBookDidChange:) name:CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil];

-(void)addressBookDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
  //Handle event here...
}
```

After a save is successfully executed, the contact store posts a CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification notification to the default notification center. If you cache any Contacts framework objects you need to refetch those objects, either by their identifiers, or with the predicates that were used to originally fetch them, and then release the cached objects. Note that cached objects are stale, but not invalid.